# PSSE user model compiling error

Tags: fortran

I have just started to learn PSSE model writing. As a starting point, I tried to compile PSSE example givem in Programe Operation Manuel page 21-16 and got the following errors. I use the Env. Manager and it seems that all paths and libs for Microsoft visual studio 2010 and Intel visual fortran 15.0 are set properly. I also set the PATH to PSSBIN folder and LIB to PSSLIB. Can anyone please suggest me where I'm going wrong?

```
The model code:
      SUBROUTINE DEMOEX(I,ISLOT)
C
      INCLUDE 'COMON4.INS'
C
      INTEGER I,ISLOT
C
C   I = MACHINE ARRAY INDEX
C   ISLOT = ARRAY ALLOCATION TABLE INDEX
C   J = STRTIN(1,ISLOT) [ USES CON(J) THROUGH CON(J+2) ]
C   K = STRTIN(2,ISLOT) [ USES STATE(K) AND STATE(K+1) ]
C
      INTRINSIC MAX, ABS
      EXTERNAL BADMID, DOCUHD
C
      INTEGER IB, J, K, IBUS, JJ
      REAL VERROR
      LOGICAL NEW
      CHARACTER IM*2
C
      IF (MODE.EQ.8)
      . CON_DSCRPT(1)='Tr'
      . CON_DSCRPT(2)='K'
      . CON_DSCRPT(3)='Te'
      . RETURN
      ...FIN
C
C    GET STARTING 'CON' AND 'STATE' INDICES
C
      J=STRTIN(1,ISLOT)
      K=STRTIN(2,ISLOT)
C
IF (MODE .GT. 4) GO TO 1000
C
C   BUS SEQUENCE NUMBER NEGATIVE IF MACHINE
C   IS OFF-LINE, SVS OR INDUCTION MACHINE
C
      IB=NUMTRM(I)
      IF (IB.LE.0) RETURN
C
      IF (MIDTRM) GO TO 900
      GO TO (100,200,300,400), MODE
C
C   MODE = 1 - INITIALIZE
C
 100  STATE(K)=ECOMP(I)
     STATE(K+1)=EFD(I)
     VREF(I)=ECOMP(I) + EFD(I)/CON(J+1)
     IF (EFD(I).LT.0.) WRITE(LPDEV,307) NUMBUS(IB),MACHID(I)
     RETURN
C
C    MODE = 2 - CALCULATE DERIVATIVES
C
 200  DSTATE(K)=(ECOMP(I)-STATE(K))/CON(J)
      VERROR=VREF(I)+VOTHSG(I)-STATE(K)
      DSTATE(K+1)=(CON(J+1)*VERROR-STATE(K+1))/CON(J+2)
      RETURN
C
C   MODE = 3 - SET EFD
C
 300  EFD(I)=MAX(STATE(K+1),0.)
      RETURN
C
C    MODE = 4 - SET NINTEG
C
 400  NINTEG=MAX(NINTEG,K+1)
      RETURN
C
C   MODE > 4
C
 1000 IM=MACHID(I)
      IB=ABS(NUMTRM(I))
      IBUS=NUMBUS(IB)
C
      IF (MODE.EQ.6) GO TO 2000
C
      TO PRINT-HEADING
C   .
      . UNLESS (NEW)
      . . NEW=.TRUE.
      . . CALL DOCUHD(*1900)
      . . WRITE(IPRT,97) IBUS,IM
      . ...FIN
C   .
      ...FIN
      END
 2000 END
```

The error messages:

```
 ifort /nologo /assume:buffered_io /traceback /libs:dll /threads /c /Qip /extend_source:132 /noaltparam
/fpscomp:logicals /Qprec /warn:nodeclarations /warn:unused /warn:truncated_source /Qauto /fp:source /iface:cvf
/define:DLLI /include:"C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE33\PSSLIB" /object:"D:\IVF15test\DEMOEX.obj"
/module:"D:\IVF15test" "D:\IVF15test\DEMOEX.f"

 D:\IVF15test\DEMOEX.f(10): error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: BLOCK
PROGRAM BLOCKDATA MODULE INTEGER REAL COMPLEX TYPE BYTE CHARACTER CLASS ...
      IF (MODE.EQ.8)
 ------------------------^
 D:\IVF15test\DEMOEX.f(11): error #5082: Syntax error, found '.' when expecting one of: <LABEL>
<END-OF-STATEMENT> ; BLOCK PROGRAM BLOCKDATA MODULE INTEGER REAL COMPLEX ...
      . CON_DSCRPT(1)='Tr'
 ----------^
 D:\IVF15test\DEMOEX.f(12): error #5082: Syntax error, found '.' when expecting one of: <LABEL>
<END-OF-STATEMENT> ; BLOCK PROGRAM BLOCKDATA MODULE INTEGER REAL COMPLEX ...
      . CON_DSCRPT(2)='K'
 ----------^
 D:\IVF15test\DEMOEX.f(13): error #5082: Syntax error, found '.' when expecting one of: <LABEL>
<END-OF-STATEMENT> ; BLOCK PROGRAM BLOCKDATA MODULE INTEGER REAL COMPLEX ...
      . CON_DSCRPT(3)='Te'
 ----------^
 D:\IVF15test\DEMOEX.f(14): error #5082: Syntax error, found '.' when expecting one of: <LABEL>
<END-OF-STATEMENT> ; BLOCK PROGRAM BLOCKDATA MODULE INTEGER REAL COMPLEX ...
      . RETURN
 ----------^
 D:\IVF15test\DEMOEX.f(15): error #5082: Syntax error, found '.' when expecting one of: <LABEL>
<END-OF-STATEMENT> ; BLOCK PROGRAM BLOCKDATA MODULE INTEGER REAL COMPLEX ...
      ...FIN
 ----------^
 D:\IVF15test\DEMOEX.f(18): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [I]
 IF (MODE .GT. 4) GO TO 1000
 ^
 D:\IVF15test\DEMOEX.f(18): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [F]
 IF (MODE .GT. 4) GO TO 1000
 -^
 D:\IVF15test\DEMOEX.f(18): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [(]
 IF (MODE .GT. 4) GO TO 1000
 ---^
 D:\IVF15test\DEMOEX.f(18): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [M]
 IF (MODE .GT. 4) GO TO 1000
 ----^
 D:\IVF15test\DEMOEX.f(18): error #5276: Unbalanced parentheses
 IF (MODE .GT. 4) GO TO 1000
 ---------------^
 D:\IVF15test\DEMOEX.f(15): catastrophic error: Could not recover from previous syntax error
 compilation aborted for D:\IVF15test\DEMOEX.f (code 1)
```

Comment: Is this FORTRAN or pseudo code? The `IF`...`FIN` statements are non-standard, and `ifort` does not know them. Maybe you need a different compiler?

Comment: In addition to what @AlexanderVogt has already written, refer to your favourite tutorial or reference guide and learn about the strict layout rules required in *fixed source form* Fortran files.  There are many SO questions and answers on the topic too, for your education so I won't repeat any here.

Comment: Thanks Alexander Vogt and High Performance Mark. I have modified IF statements. Now I'm getting 2 error messages; C:\IVFtest\PSSEtest\DEMOEX.f(25): error #6052: This label has not been defined as a FORMAT label.   [307]
           WRITE(LPDEV,307) NUMBUS(IB),MACHID(I)
 ----------------------^
 C:\IVFtest\PSSEtest\DEMOEX.f(25): error #6323: This label is not defined in this scoping unit.   [307]
           WRITE(LPDEV,307) NUMBUS(IB),MACHID(I)

Answer (score 1):

it's better to write code using fortran... but, you didn't finished flex code from pom.pdf section 21.9... I finished code in flex language, and you can compile that now without errors, but with warnings (some declared variables code didn't use etc.), I'm not sure that it will be work correct in psse environment...

```
C
C[UEXC]         05/23/02      EXAMPLE USER EXCITATION SYSTEM MODEL
C
C  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
C  *                                                                         *
C  *  THIS PROGRAM AND ITS DOCUMENTATION ARE TRADE SECRETS OF POWER TECHNO-  *
C  *  LOGIES, A DIVISION OF S&W CONSULTANTS, INC.  THEY HAVE BEEN LEASED TO  *
C  *                   YOU, OUR CLIENT,                                      *
C  *  SUBJECT TO TERMS WHICH PROHIBIT YOU FROM DISCLOSING OR TRANSFERRING    *
C  *  THE PROGRAM OR ITS DOCUMENTATION, WHETHER IN ITS ORIGINAL OR MODIFIED  *
C  *  FORM, TO A THIRD PARTY, OR FROM USING THE PROGRAM FOR ANY PURPOSE      *
C  *  OTHER THAN COMPUTATION  RELATING TO YOUR OWN SYSTEM.  ANY SUCH         *
C  *  TRANSFER OR USE BY YOU OR YOUR EMPLOYEES WILL CONSTITUTE A BREACH OF   *
C  *  CONFIDENCE AND OF THE CONTRACT UNDER WHICH RIGHTS OF USE HAVE BEEN     *
C  *  GRANTED.                                                               *
C  *                                                                         *
C  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
C
      SUBROUTINE UEXC(IARG,ISLOT)
C
C     THIS IS A SIMPLIFIED EXAMPLE EXCITATION SYSTEM MODEL
C
C                        SUBROUTINE UEXC
C    IARG   = MACHINE ARRAY INDEX
C    ISLOT  = ARRAY ALLOCATION TABLE INDEX
C             J = STRTIN(1,ISLOT) [ USES CON(J) THROUGH CON(J+8) ]
C             K = STRTIN(2,ISLOT) [ USES STATE(K) AND STATE(K+3) ]
C
C      USE DYNAMICS, ONLY:  NUMTRM,  STRTIN,
C     *                     EFD,
C     *                     ECOMP,   VOTHSG,  VREF,
C     *                     VUEL,    VOEL,
C     *                     CON,     VAR,
C     *                     STORMT,  STATE,   DSTATE,  STORE
C      USE PSSCM4,   ONLY:  NUMBUS,  BASVLT,
C     *                     BUSNAM,
C     *                     MACHID
C
C$INCLUDE PERM4.INS
C$INCLUDE DSCOM4.INS
$INSERT COMON4.INS
C
      INTEGER   IARG,   ISLOT
C
C     INTRINSIC MAX
      EXTERNAL  BADMID
C
      INTEGER   I,      J,      K,      JJ,     KK,
     *          IB,     IBUS,   IBPTR
      REAL      VERROR, VR,     DEL2,   FDBK,   SS,    R_TF_KF
      LOGICAL   HIGH,   LOW,    NEW
      CHARACTER CB1*6,  CB2*6
      CHARACTER IM*2,   VLTI*4
C
      IF (MODE.EQ.8) GO TO 1500                   ! GET DATA DESCRIPTIONS
      I=IARG                                      ! MACHINE ARRAY INDEX
      J=STRTIN(1,ISLOT)                           ! STARTING 'CON'
      K=STRTIN(2,ISLOT)                           ! STARTING 'STATE'
C
      IF (MODE.GT.4) GO TO 1000
C
      IB=NUMTRM(I)                               ! RETURN IF OFF-LINE
      IF (IB.LE.0) RETURN                        ! OR SVS OR INDUCTION MACHINE
$1
C
C MODEL NOT IMPLEMENTED FOR MSTR/MRUN
C
      IF (MIDTRM)
      .   CALL BADMID(I,IB,'UEXC')
      .   RETURN
      ...FIN
C
C     MODE 2 - CALCULATE DERIVATIVES
      IF (MODE.EQ.2)                             ! CALCULATE DERIVATIVES
C     .
      .  WHEN (MIDTRM)                           ! MODE 2 Z-FORM
C     .  the midterm simulation mode is not implemented 
C     .  .
C     .  .
      .  ...FIN
$1
      .  ELSE                                    ! STATE SPACE
C     .  MODE 2 code portion is inserted here
C     .
      .  .  HIGH=STATE(K+1).GE.CON(J+3)
C     .
      .  .  WHEN (HIGH)
      .  .  .  STATE(K+1)=CON(J+3)
      .  .  .  STORE(K+1)=CON(J+3)
      .  .  ...FIN
      .  .  ELSE
      .  .  .  LOW=STATE(K+1).LE.CON(J+4)
C     .  .  .
      .  .  .  IF (LOW)
      .  .  .  .  STATE(K+1)=CON(J+4)
      .  .  .  .  STORE(K+1)=CON(J+4)
      .  .  .  ...FIN
C     .  .  .
      .  .  ...FIN
C     .  .     
C     .  .  HANDLING SMALL TIME CONSTANTS
      .  .  DEL2=2.*DELT
C     .  .
      .  .  WHEN (CON(J).LE.DEL2)
      .  .  .  STORE(K)=ECOMP(I)
      .  .  .  STATE(K)=ECOMP(I)
      .  .  ...FIN
      .  .  ELSE DSTATE(K)=(ECOMP(I)-STATE(K))/CON(J)
C     .  .
      .  .  DSTATE(K+2)=(STATE(K+1)/CON(J+5)-STATE(K+2))*CON(J+5)/CON(J+6)
C     .  .
      .  .  FDBK=STATE(K+2)*CON(J+7)/CON(J+8)-STATE(K+3)   ! FEEDBACK BLOCK OUTPUT
      .  .  DSTATE(K+3)=FDBK/CON(J+8)
C     .  .
C     .  .  TEMPORARY VARIABLE SS
      .  .  SS=(VREF(I)+VOTHSG(I)-STATE(K)-FDBK)*CON(J+1)
C     .  .
      .  .  WHEN (CON(J+2).LE.DEL2)
      .  .  .  STORE(K+1)=SS
      .  .  .  STATE(K+1)=SS
      .  .  ...FIN
      .  .  ELSE
      .  .  .  DSTATE(K+1)=(SS-STATE(K+1))/CON(J+2)
C     .  .  .
      .  .  .  CONDITIONAL
      .  .  .  .  (HIGH) IF (DSTATE(K+1).GT.0.) DSTATE(K+1)=0.
      .  .  .  .  (LOW)  IF (DSTATE(K+1).LT.0.) DSTATE(K+1)=0.
      .  .  .  ...FIN
C     .  .  .
      .  .  ...FIN
C     .  .
      .  ...FIN
C     .
      .  RETURN
      ...FIN
$1
C     MODE 3 - SET EFD
      IF (MODE.EQ.3)
C     .
      .  WHEN (MIDTRM)                           ! RESET STORES FOR CHANGE
C     .  the midterm simulation mode is not implemented
C     .  .                                       ! IN DELT (MIDTERM)
C     .  .
      .  ...FIN
      .  ELSE EFD(I)=STATE(K+2)                  ! STATE SPACE
C     .  MODE 3 code portion is inserted here
C     .
      .  RETURN
      ...FIN
$1
C     MODE 1 - INITIALIZATION
      IF (MODE.EQ.1)                             ! INITIALIZE
      .  WHEN (MIDTRM)
C     .  the midterm simulation mode is not implemented
C     .  .
C     .  .
      .  ...FIN
      .  ELSE
C     .  MODE 1 code portion is inserted here
C     .  .  TEMPORARY VARIABLE SS
      .  .  SS=CON(J+5)*EFD(I)
      .  .  VREF(I)=ECOMP(I)+SS/CON(J+1)
C     .  .
      .  .  IF (SS.GE.CON(J+3) .OR. SS.LE.CON(J+4))
      .  .  .  WRITE(LPDEV,307) NUMBUS(IB),MACHID(I)
      .  .  ...FIN
C     .  .
      .  .  STATE(K)=ECOMP(I)
      .  .  STATE(K+1)=SS
      .  .  STATE(K+2)=EFD(I)
      .  .  STATE(K+3)=EFD(I)*CON(J+7)/CON(J+8)
      .  ...FIN
C     .
      .  RETURN
      ...FIN
C
C     MODE 4 -SET NINTEG
C     MODE 4 code portion is inserted here
      IF (K+3.GT.NINTEG) NINTEG=K+3
      RETURN
$1
C     MODE > 4
C
 1000 IM=MACHID(I)
      IB=ABS(NUMTRM(I))
      IBUS=NUMBUS(IB)
C
      IF (MODE.EQ.6) GO TO 2000
C
C     MODE 5 OR 7 - ACTIVITY DOCU
C
      IF (MODE.EQ.5)
      .  CALL DOCUHD(*1900)
      .  GO TO 1100
      ...FIN
C
$1
C     DATA CHECKING CODE
C
C     code portion # 1 for DOCU checking mode is inserted here
      NEW=.FALSE.
      DEL2=2.*DELT
C
      UNLESS (CON(J).GT.0. .AND. CON(J).LE.5.0)           ! TR
      .  PRINT-HEADING
      .  WRITE(IPRT,107) CON(J)
      ...FIN
C
      UNLESS (CON(J+1).GE.10. .AND. CON(J+1).LE.500.0)    ! KA
      .  PRINT-HEADING
      .  WRITE(IPRT,108) CON(J+1)
      ...FIN
C
      UNLESS (CON(J+2).GT.0. .AND. CON(J+2).LE.1.0)       ! TA
      .  PRINT-HEADING
      .  WRITE(IPRT,109) CON(J+2)
      ...FIN
C
      UNLESS (CON(J+3).GE.0.5 .AND. CON(J+3).LE.10.0)     ! VRMAX
      .  PRINT-HEADING
      .  WRITE(IPRT,110) CON(J+3)
      ...FIN
C
      UNLESS (CON(J+4).GE.-10.0 .AND. CON(J+4).LE.0.)     ! VRMIN
      .  PRINT-HEADING
      .  WRITE(IPRT,111) CON(J+4)
      ...FIN
C
      UNLESS (CON(J+5).GE.-1.0 .AND. CON(J+5).LE.1.0)     ! KE
      .  PRINT-HEADING
      .  WRITE(IPRT,112) CON(J+5)
      ...FIN
C
      UNLESS (CON(J+6).GT.DEL2 .AND. CON(J+6).LE.1.0)     ! TE
      .  PRINT-HEADING
      .  WRITE(IPRT,113) CON(J+6)
      ...FIN
C      
      UNLESS (CON(J+7).GE.0. .AND. CON(J+7).LE.0.3)       ! KF
      .  PRINT-HEADING
      .  WRITE(IPRT,114) CON(J+7)
      ...FIN
C
      UNLESS (CON(J+8).GT.DEL2 .AND. CON(J+8).LE.1.5)     ! TF
      .  PRINT-HEADING
      .  WRITE(IPRT,115) CON(J+8)
      ...FIN
C
      R_TF_KF=CON(J+8)/CON(J+7)
      UNLESS (R_TF_KF.GE.5.0 .AND. R_TF_KF.LE.15.0)       ! RATIO TF/KF
      .  PRINT-HEADING
      .  WRITE(IPRT,116) R_TF_KF
      ...FIN
C
C     (DATA CHECKING PERFORMED FOR ALL CONS)
C
      UNLESS (NEW) RETURN
C
C     DATA TABULATION CODE
C
 1100 JJ=J+8
      KK=K+3
C
      CALL VLTFOR(VLTI,BASVLT(IB))
      IBPTR = 0
      CALL ADINTN (JJ,CB1,IBPTR)
      IBPTR = 0
      CALL ADINTN (KK,CB2,IBPTR)
      WRITE(IPRT,17) IBUS,BUSNAM(IB),VLTI,IM,J,CB1,K,CB2
      WRITE(IPRT,27) (CON(K),K=J,JJ)
C
 1900 RETURN
C
C  MODE 6 - ACTIVITY DYDA
C
 2000 WRITE(IPRT,507) IBUS,IM,(CON(K),K=J,J+8)
      RETURN
$1
C     MODE 8 - ASSIGN DESCRIPTIONS FOR DATA EDITOR
C
C     MODE 8 code portion is inserted here
 1500 CON_DSCRPT(1) ='TR'
      CON_DSCRPT(2) ='KA'
      CON_DSCRPT(3) ='TA'
      CON_DSCRPT(4) ='VRMAX'
      CON_DSCRPT(5) ='VRMIN'
      CON_DSCRPT(6) ='KE'
      CON_DSCRPT(7) ='TE'
      CON_DSCRPT(8) ='KF'
      CON_DSCRPT(9) ='TF'
      RETURN
$1
C
C     a code portion for DOCU report is inserted here
 17   FORMAT(//6X,'** UEXC',' **  BUS   NAME   BSKV MACH',
     *       '    C O N S     S T A T E S'/,
     *       I23,1X,A8,1X,A4,2X,A2,1X,2(I7,'-',A6))
 27   FORMAT(/5X,'TR      KA     TA   VRMAX   VRMIN     KE     TE',
     *       '     KF     TF'/
     *       3X,F5.3,F8.2,2F7.3,2F8.3,3F7.3)
 97   FORMAT(//' BUS',I7,'  MACHINE ',A,':')
C
C     code portion # 2 for DOCU checking mode (messages) is inserted here
C     DOCU CHECKING MESSAGES
 107  FORMAT(' TR=',F15.4)
 108  FORMAT(' KA=',F15.4)
 109  FORMAT(' TA=',F15.4)
 110  FORMAT(' VRMAX=',F15.4)
 111  FORMAT(' VRMIN=',F15.4)
 112  FORMAT(' KE=',F15.4)
 113  FORMAT(' TE=',F15.4)
 114  FORMAT(' KF=',F15.4)
 115  FORMAT(' TF=',F15.4)
 116  FORMAT(' RATIO TF/KF=',F15.4)
C 
 307  FORMAT(' UEXC AT BUS',I7,' MACHINE ',A,
     *       ' INITIALIZED OUT OF LIMITS')
C     a code portion for DYDA record is inserted here
 507  FORMAT(I6,' ''USRMDL''',2X,A2,' ''UEXC''',1X,4G13.5,/7X,5G13.5,'/')
$1
      TO PRINT-HEADING
C     .
      .  UNLESS (NEW)
      .  .  NEW=.TRUE.
      .  .  CALL DOCUHD(*1900)
      .  .  WRITE(IPRT,97) IBUS,IM
      .  ...FIN
C     .
      ...FIN
C
      END

(FLECS Version 22.60 - PTI)
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not **Fotran** Code but **Flex** Code. You have to translate this code to Fortran.

Comment: There are several kinds of Flexes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex#Computing. Which particular Flex is it? How is the translation done?